# pThread wont work on php

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

i`m beginner in php and want to use multi threading on it
i searched and find pthread api but i have a problem to use it
i did every step exactly but it didn't work

1. i copy `php_pthreads.dll` to ext folder
2. copy `pthreadVC2.dll` to php folder
3. copy `pthreadVC2.dll` to system 32 folder
4. add `extension=php_pthreads.dll` line to `php.ini` and restart apache service

but when i add the 4 step to php.ini php show `(( 500 Internal Server Error ))`
and when i delete this line says that cant find (( Thread )) Class
any one have any  idea !!!????

Comment: Have you taken a look at the logs to see what the issue could be?

Comment: this line  shown in the  error.logs

[Thu Jun 18 16:24:01.905246 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 6140:tid 1028] [client ::1:58969] AH01215: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\php\\ext\\php_pthreads.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r: C:/php/php-cgi.exe

Answer (score 1):

The cause may be a mixing of 32-bit and 64-bit code. Make sure that php-cgi (and perhaps apache as well) are 32-bit versions.

If you prefer 64-bit, then make sure they're 64-bit and your pthread library is also 64-bit.

Comment: your right . my php version was x86 version . i changed it to x64 version but still when i add extension=php_pthreads.dll line to php.ini show error 500 .

i check error log saw this :

malformed header from script 'php-cgi.exe': Bad header: <br />
AH01215: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pthreads: Unable to initialize module: C:/php/php-cgi.exe
AH01215: Module compiled with module API=20121212: C:/php/php-cgi.exe
AH01215: PHP    compiled with module API=20131226: C:/php/php-cgi.exe
AH01215: These options need to match: C:/php/php-cgi.exe
AH01215:  in Unknown on line 0: C:/php/php-cgi.exe